# Spring boot with DB Connection to a Non database project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a project with Spring boot 1.4.1 which connects to an Oracle database, i want to generate another project with no connection to database, I removed the pom dependencies and changed the Starter code

**TO:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class App {
/**
 * Init method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args ){
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
   }
}
```

**FROM**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
/**
 * Init method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args ){
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
   }
}
```

the project still keep trying to configure database.

How can i leave the project just as a simple RestController Project with no database.

Thanks.

Comment: Changing annotations is not necessary. Can you show you properties file and your pom. Maybe you missed something

Comment: So basically you haven't changed a things... `@SpringBootApplication` is `@ComponentScan` with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@Configuration`. So they are the same. If you don't want to connect to a database remove all JDBC drivers and datasource dependencies from your pom.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of my configuration. I had included a connection in a library. After recompiling the library it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem. For me it was the Data JPA library which required data connection details, but I don't need any DB in my project.

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>Group Id Here</groupId>
    <artifactId>Artifact Id Here</artifactId>
    <version>Version Here</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This will exclude the data jpa. This way you can exclude any other problematic library in your dependency.

In your case you need to exclude the oracle dependency and it will work!